# Jquery div autoscroll only when at bottom of div

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a chat application that automatically scrolls to the bottom of the div when a new message is received. This works fine unless you're scrolled up to read the log, as when a new message is received it jumps back to the bottom. I need it to scroll only if the scroll position is already at the bottom and not sure how to do it.

```
var scroll = $("div#log").prop("scrollHeight") - $('div#log').height()
$("div#log").scrollTop(scroll)
```

Any help/suggestion would be welcome and appreciated :)

Comment: Please provide your html or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with $(document).scrollTop() and window.innerHeight.

```
function appendMessage(message) {
    if($(document).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight == $('body').height())
        /* append message and scroll */
    else
        /* append message without scroll */
});
```

see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxR9j/

Comment: it's not the window scroll but the scrollbar of a div overflow:auto

Comment: @PastorBones in that case, you can use its scrollHeight and scrollTop. see http://jsfiddle.net/vZetU/

Comment: @PastorBones offsetHeight, scrollTop and scrollHeight are property for pure javascript object. so you should get javascript object from jQuery object through `$('div.box')[0]` or `$('div.box').get(0)`. and since you append new child, scroll position is changed. so you have to inspect box's scrollHeight before you append new one. I edidted your code. see http://jsfiddle.net/NgdNz/6/

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a handler on the scroll event to check whether or not you are at the bottom of the scroll.

```
$("#mydiv").on('scroll', function() {
    ...
}
```

You can check whether or not you are at the bottom of the scroll by subtracting the scrollTop and clientHeight properties from the scrollHeight property, see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XS3kf/1/